# Why does PMD signal me that he scanner isn't closed?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, pmd

So in the following code PMD tells me the that the Scanners keyboard and scan are unclosed with a [CLoseResource] warning. I think I close I made sure that it is always closed, so I don't know what is causing this warning. The code itself works fine, and those are the only serious warnings PMD is throwing at me.

Codebit 1:

```
public static void main(final String... args) {
        Scanner scan = null;
        try {
            if (args[0].equals("-f")) {
                try {
                    scan = new Scanner(new File(args[1]));
                }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    System.exit(START_ERROR);
                }
            }else {
                System.out.println("Unbekanntes Kommando.");
                System.exit(START_ERROR);
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Nichts eingegeben.");
            System.exit(START_ERROR);
        }
        try {
            validateSize(scan);
        }catch (InvalidBoardLayoutException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            scan.close();
            System.exit(BOARD_ERROR);
        }
        scan.close();
        try {
            scan=new Scanner(new File(args[1]));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { //This should be impossible
            System.out.println("This should be impossible lmao");
            scan.close();
            System.exit(666);
        }
        try {
            validateFields(scan);
        }catch(InvalidFieldException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            scan.close();
            System.exit(BOARD_ERROR);
        }
        scan.close();
        try {
            scan=new Scanner(new File(args[1]));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { //This should be impossible
            System.out.println("This should be impossible lmao");
        }
        final Game game = new Game(scan);
        game.play();
        scan.close();
    }
```

Codebit 2:

````
        System.out.println("Enter your next move!");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String move = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (move.isEmpty()) {
            won = true;
            keyboard.close();
            return;
        }
        if (!validateFormat(move)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid format, try again.");
            return;
        }
        String[] moveAr;
        try {
            moveAr = move.split(",");
        } catch (PatternSyntaxException e) { //this should be impossible
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        try{
            validFields(moveAr);
        }catch(InvalidTurnException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        final char colour = getColour(moveAr[0]);
        for (final String s : moveAr) {
            final int line = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(1)) - 1;
            final int column = getColumn(s.charAt(0));
            this.spielFeld[line][column] = Character.toUpperCase(this.spielFeld[line][column]);
            final char columnc = s.charAt(0);
            if (columnCrossed(columnc)){
                points += crossedValues(columnc);
            }
        }
        if (colourComplete(colour)){
            points += 5;
            coloursCrossed++;
        }
        if (coloursCrossed >= 2){
            won = true;
            keyboard.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Momentane Punkte: "+points);
    }```
````

Comment: Have you considered a try-with-resources statement?

Comment: Have you considered a try-finally block?

Comment: As @Androbin was saying you should use `try-with-resource`, because your code does not guarantee that the close method will be executed it must be called within a `finally` block that is why you should always use `try-with-resource`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code in the try throws an exception that is not caught, the scanner is not closed. As already mentioned in the comments try with resources is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: This worked for keyboard,  thanks i didn't know about try with. If I try to encase scan in the same manner, it starts throwing me the warning "Cannot assign a value to final variable 'scan'" for the other assignments of scan in the codebit 1.

Comment: Nvm, I had to use each assignment as the parameter for the try block, thank you!